# Using Traefik with EC2, how does frontend rule change url

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, routes, reverse-proxy

I am new to using proxy, so I didnt quite follow why this isn't working. Not sure if this a Trafeik question, or a simple "I dont know how routing works" question

I followed the Traefik tutorial as show on their website here : https://docs.traefik.io/

Their docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

So now I wanted to run this same yml file on my ec2 instance. I make a change to the last line so that it looks like this instead:

```
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.<ec2-XXX>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

So I assumed that if I visited `http://whoami.docker.<ec2-XXX>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com`, I would see my whoami app's response. However, I get a response from my ISP that that wesbite does not exist. If I access `http://<ec2-XXX>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com:8080` I can see my Traefik console fine.

I think its got to do with web addresses, and you can only have two items before the website, like `x.y.website.com`, and the url I am using to access my ec2 is already using those two slots. I am unsure what to search for.

- Do I need to register a site/ buy a domain first?
- How would I connect this site to my ec2 instance?
- Was I correct as to why `http://whoami.docker.<ec2-XXX>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com` was not working?